# mu activate / deactivate plugins in multisite network mode only

Tags: multisite

On multisite config. I'm trying to activate a set of plugins, for example 5 additional/required plugins automatically after the first plugin is enabled. I understand you need the followings, "activate_plugin" with "network_wide", etc, but nothing I see online is functioning. The 1st (or activator plugin) only activates the plugins in single site mode. In multisite mode it seems to be skipping the other plugins that I write in the codes. I have tried 10 or 20 ways and nothing seems to function at all. I did find one code that has the deactivate that also deactivates all of the specific plugins and that also functions only in single site mode. I need help writing one for network_wide specification. Anyone?

I do not have code to post. I was hoping for a small example. It seems most people do not use this feature so I would think all people would want to learn what I have described in my question....

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress Development community! It would go a long way to better presenting the issue if you could [edit] in the code of your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: I do not have code to post. I was hoping for a small example. It seems most people do not use this feature so I would think all people would want to learn what I have described in my question....